# Can I un-jailbreak an Apple TV?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv

I'm considering switching out my Windows-based HTPC for an Apple TV unit that will stream media off a Mac in my house. This will work out okay for me as long as I can jailbreak the unit and install Plex on it. I may just opt to transcode my existing media library but I'd like to explore both options before I decide on a best solution for me.

If I jailbreak and don't like the Plex setup, can I un-jailbreak it and get it back to factory specs? How does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing a restore, similar to how one does this on an iOS device, will reset it to the factory default settings and install.

You do this by going to Settings -> General -> Reset, and selecting restore.

If that doesnt work, you can also plug it into a computer with Micro USB, and use iTunes to restore.

More information is available in this [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4367).